# How do I make a field required if another field has content in Expressionengine

Tags: field, expressionengine, channel, required

I have a channel fieldgroup called blog
This fieldgroup has 3 fields

- {body}: Textarea, required field
- {image}: file field, optional field
- {image_credit}: text field, optional field, that turns into a required field, when {image} has content.

Rationale behind this: An entry can be text only, but if an image is published it has to have credits.

As far as I´m aware of, this can´t be done natively with EE and I searched Devot-ee for an add-on, but to no avail.

I´d like to have this fixed on the field level. Ohterwise I have to write some code in the template, that will check for if {image_credit}=="" don´t publish any {image}. But this will lead to confusion, as why an image, that is shown in the CP  will not be published...

Comment: I don't believe that this is currently possible. You could add some instructions to your client for the image field and credits field explaining what will happen.

conditional requirements based on content in other fields would be a killer feature though.

Comment: I agree here - why get overly-complicated? Ask your client to use both image + caption, or neither.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any way to do this natively or with an addon, but an addon may be out there.

I'd suggest writing your own jQuery validation. You can pop it into the instructions for one of the fields on that channel form. Should do the trick nicely

Comment: This is a great solution in combination with the "CP CSS & JS" add-on referenced in the answer posted by @Tyssen

Answer (score 2):

If you have `Pixel&Tonic's` Matrix add-on installed,  you could create a new Matrix field in this Channel's field group.

The Matrix field has zero rows by default, and contains two field columns within:

- Image field for the pic (*required*)
- Text field for caption (*required*)

So, if there's an image with this entry, the client clicks the `plus` icon to create a row, and must fill in both the image and caption.  If there's no image, they leave it as is.

Answer (score 1):

Pixel & Tonic also have [this addon](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cp-css-js) which enables you to add your own custom js to the control panel. So you could do a check to see if the image field has content and then prevent the form from being submitted if the caption field is empty.